# Threading Task not executing in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, iis, task

I have a .Net application that uses Forms Authentication mode and has a function that calls an asynchronous task. Below is the snippet of the task:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { UploadFunction(); }, tokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,TaskScheduler.Default);
```

The thread is working fine when I test in on the Visual Studio IDE. The issue is when I deploy it, the threading task seems to be skipped or not executed by the system.

I've read an article that this can be caused by permissions in IIS:

http://codemine.net/post/Thread-Not-working-in-Aspnet-When-deployed-to-IIS

Tweaking the solution on above article to be implemented in Forms authentication, below is the code for that:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "LogonUser")]
private static extern bool LogonUser(
         string lpszUsername,
         string lpszDomain,
         string lpszPassword,
         int dwLogonType,
         int dwLogonProvider,
         ref IntPtr phToken);

    public JsonResult uploadimages(){

         try{

            IntPtr token = new IntPtr(0);
                        token = IntPtr.Zero;

                        bool returnValue = LogonUser("Administrator", "WIN-82CH4949B3Q", "Neuron14",
                                         3,
                                         0,
                                         ref token);

            WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(token);
            WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate();

            var task2 =     Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { UploadFunction(); }, tokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,TaskScheduler.Default);

            impersonatedUser.Undo();

            return Json(new { message = "Success" }, "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

         }

         catch (ex Exception)
         {
            return Json(new { error= ex.Message }, "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
         }
    }
```

Implementing the above code to the system still does not execute the thread once deployed in IIS. I'm really having a hard time fixing this since I do not really know why the thread is not executing when deployed.

Comment: Why couldn't it? Pass all necessary data to the function. Also, the task is not "skipped". Make sure you are being notified of all errors. Fire-and-forget is not viable in production because errors go missing.

Comment: So the implementation above is a fire-and-forget one? All necessary data are passed. I'm not that sure about the error-trapping. How can I ensure that the code notify the system for all the errors?

Comment: Not observing the result of a task is fire and forget in my book. Make sure that UploadFunction has a try-catch-all and sends you a mail for every error. The post you linked to was about extracting data on the request thread and passing that into the worker thread/task. What's the significance of that post to your situation? Seems like you can use the same approach.

Comment: The issue that the article raised wherein his code is thread is not working when deployed is the same issue as mine. The article used directly used System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity. I cannot use that since I am using Form Authentication Mode.

Comment: So why don't you use the equivalent of Forms Authentication Mode? Seems to be FormsIdentity or IIdentity.

Comment: Today, I tried to used Windows Impersonation in Forms Authentication Mode, see my updated question.

But still once I deploy it, the thread does not execute.

Comment: I don't see any error checking. No suprise that you don't know why the thread "does not execute". (It executes but it probably errors out. Or, the request crashes before that.)

Comment: I did not put the entire code, but I did enclosed the actual code with a try-catch. I will edit my question, sorry for my question's vagueness.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem when you attempt to impersonate a windows identity:

```
WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(token);
WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate();

var task2 =     Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { UploadFunction(); }, tokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,TaskScheduler.Default);

impersonatedUser.Undo();
```

The problem is that the `Impersonate` function only applies for that thread, and your `UploadFunction` is running on a different thread.

Here's a modification to your code which has the `Impersonate` method called on the background task's thread:

```
WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(token);
var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
                                 {
                                     using(WindowsImpersonationContext wi = newId.Impersonate())
                                     {
                                          UploadFunction();
                                     }
                                 },
                                 tokenSource.Token,
                                 TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
                                 TaskScheduler.Default
                               );
```

My guess is that it worked on your local machine because you were uploading to a folder which allowed anonymous access. The permissions on your production server would be much tighter.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I tried your code but still it did not work on IIS. Any thoughts on how I can configure the anonymous access in the server? Thanks.