# net core thread not executing in IIS

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis, asp.net-core, service

I am doing a `Net Core 2.0 Application`... On the `startup.cs ConfigureServices` method I implement a  IHostedService to call a task.

```html
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
             services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, TimedHostedService>();             
}
             
public class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        //private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private Timer _timer;


        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //_logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is starting.");

            _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private void DoWork(object state)
        {
            //go to database

            //_logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is working.");
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
          //  _logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is stopping.");

            _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _timer?.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

When I publish the Project, and i run it from Console `dotnet Project.dll`, the services is executed fine. But I run it from IIS, the thread never is excecuted.

I have read  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989420/threading-task-not-executing-in-iis) post, but does not help.

What I am missing?

Thanks...

Comment: you start the thread, but then leave the function with it potentially still running, and as it's scope is that function it should get disposed.  Maybe make the thread static?

Comment: Are you sure ConfigureServices is being called?

Comment: Why are you trying to use a thread in the first place? Each HTTP request is already served by a separate thread. As for running long running tasks in the background, the correct way to do it is to [use IHostedService and BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where am I supposed to start persistent background tasks in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178792/where-am-i-supposed-to-start-persistent-background-tasks-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: Thanks, I am using IHostedServices and have the same problem. I updated the error descrition.